# What is the difference between json_encode($response, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) and json_encode($response)?

Tags: php, json, decode

How the output in following two json encoding methods in php differs ? Can anyone help me with the decoding options for both.?

```
json_encode($response, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); 
json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Have you tried to look at what the difference in output is?

Comment: I am new to json. So it seems difficult to figure it out.

Comment: Have you [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)?

Comment: Your question is Unclear because you are asking about both encoding and decoding.  Please clarify/improve your question.   If you have follow up questions for those who provide answers, then you have probably posted an incomplete question.  Please ask your single, isolated, clear question in the original posted question.  Again, please edit.  Give us your sample input data and expected output in the question (not comments).

Comment: I want to decode $jsonvar='{"output":{"0":{"userid":"100"}}}"' to php array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please Check Bellow Example. You will know both method.**

> ```
> <?php
> $b = array();
>
> echo "Empty array output as array: ", json_encode($b), "\n";
> echo "Empty array output as object: ", json_encode($b, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT), "\n\n";
>
> $c = array(array(1,2,3));
>
> echo "Non-associative array output as array: ", json_encode($c), "\n";
> echo "Non-associative array output as object: ", json_encode($c, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT), "\n\n";
>
> $d = array('foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'long');
>
> echo "Associative array always output as object: ", json_encode($d), "\n";
> echo "Associative array always output as object: ", json_encode($d, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT), "\n\n";
> ?>
> ```

## OUTPUT

> ```
> Empty array output as array: []
> Empty array output as object: {}
>
> Non-associative array output as array: [[1,2,3]]
> Non-associative array output as object: {"0":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3}}
>
> Associative array always output as object: {"foo":"bar","baz":"long"}
> Associative array always output as object: {"foo":"bar","baz":"long"}
> ```

Comment: How to decode {"0":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3}}  object to array?

Comment: $data = {"0":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3}};
json_decode($data) // it will return value in object format ===========
json_decode($data, true) // it will return in array format

Comment: I tried it for my json encoded object . $jsonvar='{"output":{"0":{"userid":"100"}}}"';   but decoding not working , is there any problem with my json object?

Comment: '{"output":{"0":{"userid":"100"}}}"' is json decoded string. please encode array and decode it. You will get result

Comment: I am getting response from api as above json decoded string. How can I handle with this string?

Comment: response is in json format. if yes please give me the response.

Comment: "{"output":{"0":{"iUserId":"100","vUserName":"TEST","cP1":"N","cP2":"N","cP3":"N","cP4":"N","cP5":"N","cPanStatus":"Y","tPhoto":"","tpan_image":"","tbank_image":"","taddress_image":"","caddressPhotoStatus":"","cpanPhotoStatus":"","cbankPhotoStatus":"","cPhotoStatus":"N","cSMSStatus":"N","iPV":"1","cGuestStatus":"B","vCardName":"","vCardRelation":"","SBS_SFS":"0","cMonthStatus":"Y","OTP_VERIF":"0","mtRegId":"0","mtRegConfirm":"0"}}}"

Comment: $data =  
"{"output":{"0":{"iUserId":"100","vUserName":"TEST","cP1":"N‌​","cP2":"N","cP3":"N‌​","cP4":"N","cP5":"N‌​","cPanStatus":"Y","‌​tPhoto":"","tpan_ima‌​ge":"","tbank_image"‌​:"","taddress_image"‌​:"","caddressPhotoSt‌​atus":"","cpanPhotoS‌​tatus":"","cbankPhot‌​oStatus":"","cPhotoS‌​tatus":"N","cSMSStat‌​us":"N","iPV":"1","c‌​GuestStatus":"B","vC‌​ardName":"","vCardRe‌​lation":"","SBS_SFS"‌​:"0","cMonthStatus":‌​"Y","OTP_VERIF":"0",‌​"mtRegId":"0","mtReg‌​Confirm":"0"}}}";

$output_arr = json_decode($data, true);

echo '<pre/>';print_r($output_arr);exit;
now please check.

Comment: It outputs blank page.

Comment: It is encoded using json_encode($response, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

Answer (score 1):

The point is that if this option `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` is "enabled", the deserialized array will be placed in the object:

```
$c = array(array(1,2,3));

echo "Non-associative array output as array: ", json_encode($c), "\n";
echo "Non-associative array output as object: ", json_encode($c, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT), "\n\n";
```

> Non-associative array output as array: [[1,2,3]] 
> Non-associative array output as object: {"0":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3}}